# neon-glow effect in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, effects

The following css creates a nice neon-glow effect around text

```
{
    text-shadow: 0em 0em 0.3em white; /* assuming a dark background */
}
```

However it doesn't work in IE7/8

For a reference, compare [this page](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/text-shadow) in Firefox and IE

Is there a way to get a similar effect in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Won't work in IE8, since `text-shadow` is a feature of upcoming CSS3. However you might add a secondary rule for IE7/8, called `filter:Glow` (invalid CSS syntax, proprietary to Microsoft).

You can get [more info on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532995(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: hmm, interesting. but the examples on that link are quite ugly

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed, text-shadow only works in modern browsers. IE has something that might help in their proprietary filters called glow but I don't know anything beyond that.